# Overlook UIAppearance proxy for random subviews & not whole class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiappearance

I am using the UIAppearance protocol to set the text alignment of UILabel throughout my app in appDelegate.

```
[[UILabel appearance] setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentNatural];
```

Natural text alignment is preferred to cover RTL & LTR language support. But there are some case where I need to keep UILabel as center aligned or right aligned only. That class may have mix approach like some Natural alignment supported & some specific alignment so below code wont be applicable.

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyClass class], nil]];
```

I have tried to set explicitly text alignment of particular UILabel instance but it is not getting applied. Anyone have come across such scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explicitly changed expected text alignment for UILabel in "viewWillAppear" for any controller & for table view cell,I applied same changes at "awakeFromNib" & it worked fine. I tried to do it in "layoutSubview" method which DID NOT work.

I believe if you are creating any UILabel programmatically then you can set specific textAlignment which will override UIAppearance proxy work. I have not tested this part.

I hope this will be helpful & save someones time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Interface Builder(IB)/Storybaord you could create custom subclasses of UILabel for the desired format, assign the custom class in IB and then apply the UIAppearance proxy to those custom subclasses.

```
 [[CenterLabel appearance] setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
 [[NaturalLabel appearance] setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentNatural];
```

This would allow you to mix and match different label types within the same class without having to use the *appearanceWhenContainedIn* restriction.

Comment: Thanks for your views ...Actually I am doing it for existing code & code base is huge to do all these stuffs. In fact I tried same solution of subclassing for one module & it works fine ..